# Consulta sql problema inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByEF7.png)

Hola, tengo un problema y es que tengo tres tablas (profesores,habilidades y la tabla que relaciona estas dos que se llama habilidadxprofesor)beno lo que pasa es que genero la consulta:

```
select * from profesores 
join habilidadesxprofesor 
on profesores.id_profesor=habilidadesxprofesor.id_profesor 
inner join habilidades  
on habilidadesxprofesor.id_habilidad=habilidades.id_habilidad ;
```

pero no me devuelve ningun resultado, creo que hay un problema en el ultimo join pero no soy experto de hecho soy nuevo por lo cual solicito su ayuda, gracias de antemano, por cierto la consulta hace referencia a esto :Muestre el nombre de los profesores que cuenten entre sus habilidades con
“Instructor CCNA” y “Conocimientos de IoT”

Comment: ya borre las dos

Comment: avance un poco pero decide explicarme bien y borrar las otras,mis disculpas

Comment: select * from profesores 
join habilidadesxprofesor 
on profesores.id_profesor=habilidadesxprofesor.id_profesor ; si hago esta consulta si me muestra los nombres de los profesores y sus respectivas id_habilidades pero al relacionar la otra tabla no devulve consultas

Comment: id_profesor=1 nombre_profesor=Esteban Marín cedula_profesor108762434 id_habilidad=1 id_profesor=1
2 Katya Brenes 204534123 1 2

Comment: hola me parece perfecta tu consulta pero no devulve datos, ya me imigino debe ser que la base esta mal hecha de todos modos gracias!!

Comment: se pueden anadir tres imagenes?

Comment: salvo que sean estrictamente necesarias puede ser que si, en caso contrario pega la muestra de los datos de las 3 tablas como texto, posterior seleccionalo y presiona `ctrl + k` para darle formato

Comment: listo, ya las agregue

Comment: usa este fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/ y aquí replica tu ejercicio, primero crea la tabla profesores, luego la tabla habilidades y luego la tabla pivote, inserta los datos de todas y ejecuta mi consulta; una vez hecho eso coloca aquí en los comentarios el link de tu fiddle copiando la URL para verificarlo

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que esta incompleta tu consulta, pues lo que invoques en el `SELECT` serán los valores que te retorne:

```
SELECT profesores.nombre_profesor, habilidades.descripcion_habilidad
FROM profesores
JOIN habilidadesXprofesor ON profesores.id_profesor = habilidadesXprofesor.id_profesor
JOIN habilidades ON habilidades.id_habilidad = habilidadesXprofesor.id_habilidad;
```

- Primero debes poner en el `SELECT` los valores de las 2 tablas que deseas recuperar (yo solo puse 2 pero tu puedes indicar mas)
- En el primer `JOIN` puedes indicar la relación entre la PK de `profesores` y la FK de `habilidadesXprofesor`
- En el segundo `JOIN` puedes indicar la relación entre la PK de `habilidades` y la FK de `habilidadesXprofesor`

Por último para limitar los resultados a los 2 parámetros que indicas, pudieras hacer después del último `JOIN` así:

```
WHERE habilidades.descripcion_habilidad IN ("Instructor CCNA", "Conocimientos de IoT");
```

Lo anterior equivale a usar el operador `OR` entre cada comparación; sin embargo se puede modificar la consulta así:

```
WHERE habilidades.descripcion_habilidad = "Instructor CCNA"
AND habilidades.descripcion_habilidad = "Conocimientos de IoT";
```

Igual después del último `JOIN`